# SQL database not being sorted correctly into ListView

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have an SQL database with multiple columns which I use with a simpleCursorAdapter to show it inside a listview. I would like to sort my database on the Integer Column `COL3`. I am aware of how this should be done, however, my attempts did not sort the data. I am not fully sure if I've placed it incorrectly but I would greatly appreciate the help.

DatabaseHelper.java

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                COL2 +" TEXT, " + COL3 + " INTEGER, '" + COL4 + "' TEXT, '" + COL5 + "'INTEGER, '" + COL6 + "'INTEGER, '" + COL7 + "'INTEGER, '" + COL8 + "'INTEGER)";
        db.execSQL(createTable);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean addData(String item, String desc, int pri, int strat, int person, int urgen) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL2, item);
        contentValues.put(COL4, desc);
        contentValues.put(COL3, pri);
        contentValues.put(COL6, strat);
        contentValues.put(COL7, person);
        contentValues.put(COL8, urgen);

        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " ORDER BY " + COL3 + " DESC";
        db.rawQuery(query, null);

        Log.d(TAG, "addData: Adding " + item + " to " + TABLE_NAME);
        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

        //if data as inserted incorrectly it will return -1
        if (result == -1) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    } 
public Cursor getData(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
        Cursor data = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        return data;
    }
    public Cursor getItemID(String name){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT " + COL1 + " FROM " + TABLE_NAME +
                " WHERE " + COL2 + " = '" + name + "'";
        Cursor data = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        return data;
    } 
    public String[] databaseToStringArray() {
        String[] fromColumns = new String[]{COL2, COL4};
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(" SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE 1 ", null);

        if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount()>0) {
            Log.d("Event", "Records do exist");
        }
        else {
            Log.d("Event", "Records do not exist");
        }


        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        db.close();
        return fromColumns;
    }
}
```

If you would like me to elaborate or provide further information I would be happy to. Thanks in advance

Comment: You don't sort as you add data. You sort when you query for the records you need. That `db.rawQuery()` call isn't really doing anything there. That call will return a `Cursor` with the records sorted, and that's what you'd use for your `ListView`. If I'm assuming correctly, just replace the `SELECT` statement in `getData()` with the one you currently have in `addData()`, and remove the `db.rawQuery()` from `addData()`.

Comment: @MikeM. Oh thanks! I didnt realise it was such a small mistake on my part. Much appreciated

Comment: Hey @MikeM.  Make that an answer so that it can be accepted and that other people can find it?

Answer (score 0):

Your code :-

```
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " ORDER BY " + COL3 + " DESC";
    db.rawQuery(query, null);
```

Will extract the data into a Cursor sorted as you have specified. However, the Cursor is not used. This will have no affect on the Table itself where the data is stored where available space exists.

What you need to do include the sort (ORDER BY COL3) in the query that returns the Cursor (the **getData** method appears to this method) that is used as the source of the ListView.

If the above assumption is correct then the **getData** method could be :-

```
public Cursor getData(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " ORDER BY " + COL3 + " DESC";
    return db.rawQuery(query, null);
}
```

- Note the simpler direct return of Cursor

The above lines serve no useful purpose inside the **addData** method and should be removed. As such the **addData** method could be :-

```
public boolean addData(String item, String desc, int pri, int strat, int person, int urgen) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL2, item);
    contentValues.put(COL4, desc);
    contentValues.put(COL3, pri);
    contentValues.put(COL6, strat);
    contentValues.put(COL7, person);
    contentValues.put(COL8, urgen);

    Log.d(TAG, "addData: Adding " + item + " to " + TABLE_NAME);
    return (db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues) > 0);
}
```

- Note the simpler/alternative code for determining true or false for the return.